# Getting the list of files sorted by modification date in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, date

I am trying to get the list of files sorted by modification date. I modified the sample program from *[Sort Directory and list files based on date and time](http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/sort-directory-and-list-files-based-on-date-and-time-317220.html)*  and tried to run it.

```
sub get_sorted_files {
    my $path = shift;
    opendir my($dir), $path or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
    my %hash = map {$_ => (stat($_))[9]}
               map  { "$dir$_" }
               grep { m/.*/i }
               readdir $dir;
    closedir $dir;
    return %hash;
}

my %files = get_sorted_files(".");
foreach my $keys (sort{$files{$a} <=> $files{$b}} keys %files) {
    print "$keys\t", scalar localtime($files{$keys}), "\n";
}
```

I am running this on my Windows XP 32-bit machine using [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl) version 5.12.1.0.

The directory listing on Windows is:

[image]

The output is:

[image]

The output doesn't make much sense to me. What is going wrong with this piece of code and how exactly is the `foreach` loop sorting the list of files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `get_sorted_files`, `$dir` is a glob, not the directory name. Perhaps you meant `$path`?

```
my %hash = map {$_ => (stat($_))[9]}
           map  { "$path/$_" }              # $path, not $dir
           grep { m/.*/i }
           readdir $dir;
```

Comment: Thank you mob! My bad couldn't catch it earlier!

Answer (score 8):

There are at least 2 problems with that code.  Here's a better version:

```
use strict;
use warnings; # I bet you weren't using this, because it produced a lot

sub get_sorted_files {
   my $path = shift;
   opendir my($dir), $path or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
   my %hash = map {$_ => (stat($_))[9] || undef} # avoid empty list
           map  { "$path$_" }
           readdir $dir;
   closedir $dir;
   return %hash;
}

my %files = get_sorted_files("./");
foreach my $key (sort{$files{$a} <=> $files{$b}} keys %files) {
   print "$key\t", scalar localtime($files{$key}), "\n";
}
```

First, you renamed `$dir` in the original code to `$path`, but didn't change it in the `map` line.  Your `$dir` is a directory handle; that's where the GLOB(0x...) is coming from.

Second, all the modification dates read "Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969" because you were passing a bad pathname to `stat`.  `(stat($_))[9]` was returning an empty list (because you were looking for a file like `GLOB(0x3f9b38)status.txt` instead of the correct pathname) and so the hash actually wound up containing filenames as both keys and values.  The first filename was a key, the second was its value, the third was the next key, and so on.  `localtime` was converting the filename to a number (yielding 0), and then converting epoch time 0 (1-Jan-1970 0:00:00 UTC) to your timezone.

Third, it expects `$path` to end with a directory separator, and you were passing `"."`.  You'd need to pass `"./"`, or better yet, fix it so the function appends a separator if needed.

Fourth, the `grep` no longer did anything and should be removed.  (In the original code, it selected only certain filenames, but you'd changed the pattern to match anything.)

As for how it sorts filenames:  `get_sorted_files` returns a list of pathnames and modification times, which you store into the `%files` hash.  `keys %files` returns the list of keys (the filenames) and sorts them by a numeric comparison of the associated value (the modification time).

Comment: Thanks a bunch cjm! Bad on my part not to catch that! Learnt quite a bit from your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)'s [sort](http://raleigh.pm.org/sorting.html) function. It's faster and you'll get what you want without the hash.

> Size of file, then age of file:
>
> @s = sort {-s $a <=> -s $b || -M $b <=> -M $a} @a;

Knowing the above, we can say something like the below:

```
sub get_sorted_files {
   my $path = shift;
   opendir my($dirh), $path or die "can't opendir $path: $!";
   my @flist = sort {  -M $a <=> -M $b } # Sort by modification time
               map  { "$path/$_" } # We need full paths for sorting
               readdir $dirh;
   closedir $dirh;
   return @flist;
}
```

Comment: This won't be that fast: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=393128

Answer (score 1):

For really large directories, you may find that [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) is significantly slower than using the native tools to do the sorting. For instance, on my machine, on an enormous (341k files) directory, this takes about 1.5 minutes:

```
my $mostrecent = `/bin/ls --full-time -lta $dir | head -1 2>/dev/null`;
```

But the code in the solution above (using `opendir` and `sort -M`) takes from 30-45 seconds longer. Not only is it significantly faster, you can also avoid Perl storing the whole array in memory, which can be a win on its own.

Note that the above is on a fairly high-end Linux blade system, so YMMV per computer/OS...

Answer (score 0):

With a one-liner:

```
perl -E '
    say join "\n",
    sort { -M $a <=> -M $b }
    grep -f, @ARGV
' -- *
```

Comment: This is going to be pretty slow when you get over about 50 files: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=393128

Comment: I don't agree: https://hastebin.com/share/vonexagedi.swift On 10000 files I get `real 0m0,357s` I agree Schwarzien transform should be better, but the conciseness of this command have his place IMHO...