# How to untar files from youngest to oldest one until success in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, tar

I got a list of tar files(backups) in a directory and need to untar them trying from the youngest to the oldest one until success.

The problem is that from time to time tar files are damaged and need to untar older one.

this is how I find the youngest one but not sure how to put this in while and find next one.

```
tar -xf `find /config/config_*.tar -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -hat | head -n 1`
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a working `find | xargs ls` that gives you the sorted list of files, newest first.  (As @sjsam points out, that assumes none of your filenames include newlines.)  You can use the [process-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) feature of bash to put that list in a file, one entry per line, so that it can be re[ad by a `while ... read` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#description).  Then you can exit the loop as soon as one backup succeeds.

```
    # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv get the next filename into $tarname
while IFS= read -r tarname
do  
    tar -xf "$tarname" && break
                    #  ^^^^^^^^ done with the loop if tar succeeds
done <   <(find /config/config_*.tar -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -hat)  
   # ^   ^^^^---- the process substitution
   # |
   # +--------- the redirection from the process subsitution
```

Note that you do need `< <(...)`, not just `<(...)`.

(By the way, do you need `ls -hat`, or would `ls -t` do as well?)

---

**Edit!** aka **Take 3**

I was inspired by @sjsam's comment to write [ls0](https://github.com/cxw42/ls0), a `ls` replacement that can provide NULL-terminated output.  Check it out and file an issue if you find any bugs!  It was tested with Perl 5.22 on Cygwin, but should work for most Perl 5s.  It is a single file — to install, put `ls0` in your path and `chmod ugo+x ls0`.

Using `ls0`, the technique above can handle strangely-named files with aplomb:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' tarname
do  
    tar -xf "$tarname" && break
done <   <(find /config/config_*.tar -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -print0 | ls0 -t)
```

(as @sjsam noted, `-d ''` is functionally equivalent to `-d $'\0'`)

---

**Take 2** The [page sjsam links](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#Why_you_shouldn.27t_parse_the_output_of_ls.281.29) suggests using `perl` instead of `ls` to sort the filenames.  That way you can handle filenames that have newlines or other strange characters in them.

Here's an example of that technique (*not the answer to the OP's question*).  I have tested it with a filename including a newline.  The following code prints the `*.tar` files in the current directory, newest first.  This example prints a slash before and after each filename so you can see that filenames with newlines are handled correctly.  Tested on cygwin, bash 4.3.46, perl 5.22.2.

```
perl -e 'opendir(my $dirh, "."); print(join "\0", sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep /.tar$/, readdir($dirh))' \ 
| while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' name
do 
    printf "/%s/\n" "$name"
done
```

So, putting that all together for code that (1) answers the OP's question and (2) is robust to filenames with strange contents:

```
perl -e 'opendir(my $dirh, "."); print(join "\0", sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep /.tar$/, readdir($dirh))' \ 
| while read -r -d $'\0' tarname
do
    tar -xf "$tarname" && break
done
```

Or, using process substitution,

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' tarname
do
    tar -xf "$tarname" && break
done < <(perl -e 'opendir(my $dirh, "."); print(join "\0", sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep /.tar$/, readdir($dirh))')
```

Easy, right? ;)

Sources:

- reading directories in sorted order: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13999717/2877364)

  - [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for the `-M` test
- reading null-terminated data in bash: [this blog post](http://transnum.blogspot.com/2008/11/bashs-read-built-in-supports-0-as.html) (bash's `read` can be used with null-terminated strings)
- filtering a list in perl: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960071/2877364)

Comment: It is [\[ not suggested \]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#Why_you_shouldn.27t_parse_the_output_of_ls.281.29) to parse the output of ls.

Comment: I used first version since there are no spaces in a name.

Comment: @sjsam Check out [ls0](https://github.com/cxw42/ls0) - now you don't have to parse the output of `ls` any more!  What do you think?  Thanks for the [wooledge link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#Why_you_shouldn.27t_parse_the_output_of_ls.281.29), which gave me the inspiration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Below script will do

```
find /path/to/tarball/folder -type f -name "*.tar" -printf "%A@--%p\0" |
sort -rnz | while read -r -d '' stampedfile 
do
  tar -xzf "${stampedfile#*--}" >/dev/null 2>&1
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Newest Working Tar: ${stampedfile#*--}" && exit
done
```

**What we have done**

- Use `find` to list the null terminated tarball files which are prepended by the last accessed time in seconds since epoch and a `--` which we use as delimiter later
- sort the filenames in the descending order using the time of modification. This is where the `--` delimiter comes in handy
- parse the null terminated sorted files using a while loop
- strip the `time--` from the filenames and attempt to untar it
- If the attempt is successful, then **exit**

Comment: Good stuff, but why the clumsy test of `$?`? (I assume `$0` is a typo)  You could simply `&& exit` directly following `tar` (or even, `while read && !tar; do echo failure >&2; done`)

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that this will accumulate partial results from the failed tar invocations, which might not be what's wanted - in which case, you might need to perform a dry-run pass with each file before using the first successful one.  It's not clear from the question what's wanted, though.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Thanks for the pointer on `$?`. And yes! multiple ways of shortening this one. I put the longer one for the sake of explanation. :) Cheerz

Comment: @sjsam Shouldn't `"${stampedfile##*--}"` be `"${stampedfile#*--}"` (shortest-match) in case the name of the tar includes a `--`?

Comment: @cxw nice point, incorporated..ideally the delimiter should be so unique that it shouldn't be present in the file names